# How to use JavaScript with repeated elements with same ids in one page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am building a wordpress website, and I am facing problems with JavaScript implementation in one of the pages.

I am using a plugin for question and answer functionality in my website. I want to add a star rating for each user answer in this page. I added a div in HTML and JavaScript to change this div to display stars according to the user’s star value fetched from database.

The problem that I am having is: after I added code (div and JavaScript) to this plugin PHP file (which displays answers for question answer plugin) only the first user’s answer star value is changed. The rest of star display is showing full 5 stars.

How do I deal with repeated elements with same id in the same page?

[image: Image showing the answer part of the webpage]

Here is part of the plugin php file (which displays answers for question answer plugin)

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class() ?> ap-id="<?php 
the_ID(); ?>" ap="answer">
<div class="ap-content" itemprop="suggestedAnswer<?php echo ap_is_selected() 
? ' acceptedAnswer' : ''; ?>" itemscope 
itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
<div class="ap-single-vote"><?php ap_vote_btn(); ?></div>
<div class="ap-avatar"> 
<a href="<?php ap_profile_link(); ?>"<?php ap_hover_card_attr(); ?>>
<?php ap_author_avatar( ap_opt( 'avatar_size_qanswer' ) ); ?>
</a>
</div>
<div class="ap-cell clearfix">
<div class="ap-cell-inner">
<div class="ap-q-metas">
<?php echo ap_user_display_name( [ 'html' => true ] ); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ap-posted">
<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?php echo ap_get_time( 
get_the_ID(), 'c' ); ?>">
<?php printf( 'Posted %s', ap_human_time( ap_get_time( get_the_ID(), 'U' ) ) 
 ); ?>
</time>
 </a>
 <?php ap_recent_post_activity(); ?>
 <?php echo ap_post_status_badge( ); // xss okay.   ?>
  </div>

  <div class="ap-q-inner">
  <?php  //star rating data fetch from database.
   $_postx = ap_get_post();
   $curru_ID=$_postx->post_author;
   $answertitle=get_the_title();


   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sitedata");
   $ratevalue1=mysqli_query($con,"select rating from ratings where 
   Name='$answertitle' AND postID='$curru_ID'");
   $ratevaluearr1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ratevalue1);
   $ratingonequery=$ratevaluearr1[rating];
   $ratenamevalue1=mysqli_query($con,"select ratingname from ratings where 
   Name='$answertitle' AND postID='$curru_ID'");
   $ratenamevaluearr1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ratenamevalue1);
   $ratingnameonequery=$ratenamevaluearr1[ratingname];
    ?>
    <?php 
    do_action( 'ap_before_answer_content' );
    ?>
    <div class="ap-answer-content ap-q-content" itemprop="text" ap-content>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    do_action( 'ap_after_answer_content' );
    ?>

    </div>

    <div id="rate1" class="rating"></div>   
    <?php if ( ap_user_can_read_answer( ) ) : ?>
    <div class="ap-post-footer clearfix">
    <?php echo ap_select_answer_btn_html( ); // xss okay ?>
    <?php ap_post_actions_buttons() ?>
    <?php echo ap_comment_btn_html(); // xss okay. ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php ap_the_comments(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var cw = window.rate1.clientWidth; // save original 100% pixel width
    var userstarvalue = "<?php echo $ratingonequery ?>";
    rating(userstarvalue);
    function rating( stars ) {
    var ratingfill=stars;
       var rating_integer=Math.floor(ratingfill);
       var rating_decimal=ratingfill%1;
       var rating_dec_trimmed=rating_decimal.toFixed(1);  
       if((rating_dec_trimmed==0.1)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.2)||
          (rating_dec_trimmed==0.3)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.4))
       {
             window.rate1.style.width = ((40*rating_integer)+18) + 'px';
       }
       if((rating_dec_trimmed==0.6)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.7)||
          (rating_dec_trimmed==0.8)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.9))
       {
             window.rate1.style.width = ((40*rating_integer)+28) + 'px';
       }
       if(rating_dec_trimmed==0.5)
       {
             window.rate1.style.width = ((40*rating_integer)+20) + 'px';
       }
       if(rating_dec_trimmed==0)
       {
             window.rate1.style.width = (40*rating_integer) + 'px';
       }
  } 
   </script>    
   <style>
   .rating {
   font-size: 48px;
   color: #0095f9;
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: hidden;
      }
.rating::before { 
   content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605" 
}
   </style>
```

Comment: You cannot have same id for more than 1 elements

Comment: You can, it's just not convention.

Answer (score 1):

First of all multiple elements should not have the same `id` but the same `class`. It won't throw an error but is not a convention.

You can use `jQuery` and the `each` functionality to iterate through all the occurrences with same id or class.

```
$('.rating').each(function(index, object) {
    //logic here
});
```

'index' is the postion in the array, 'object' is the DOM object (with the class `rating`).

Comment: `.rating` indicates a `class` called `rating` and not an `id`

Comment: Yeah, in his original question he mentioned `id` so just clarifying that.

Comment: You have written code for doing same logic to every element in rating class.But here it's not the case.Every user will have different star rating value given by the user fetched from database.Answer.php(code given in question) is used in plugin to display each user's answer in one page.

Comment: When i use javascript,only 1 id is manipulated and rest of similar repeated elements with same id are not responding to javascript.

Comment: @mrinalmech,i didn't get what you meant in your answer.Can you show how to implement this in my code with your code?Can you show how to do it fully?

Comment: @codewiz What does this return? `var userstarvalue = "<?php echo $userstarvaluerating ?>";`. It's only the `userstarvalue` for one person right? How would you get all of the star values from the `PHP`?

Comment: Yes,var userstarvalue returns star value for one user of that answer.

Comment: How would one get for all users? You'll need to get for all the users so you can modify for all of the frontend stars.

Comment: For each answer,id and other related data is collected from plugin php file and star value matching that is fetched from database.

Comment: Can you post the PHP file too. Very difficult to get an idea with just this information.

Comment: @mrinalmech,i now included full php file in the question.

Comment: @mrinalmech,above php file is answer part of question answer plugin,  called as answer.php.Answer.php gives answers given by different users in one page.

Comment: @mrinalmech,did you get any solutions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144225/discussion-between-mrinalmech-and-codewiz).